# nginx How change/modify proxy header response?

Tags: nginx, proxy, response

I'm using nginx as reverse proxy for some domain my configuration for domain looks like that,

```
server
        {
                listen       80;
                server_name www.mydomain.com mydomain.com;
                index index.html index.htm index.php default.html default.htm;
location / {
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_pass http://www.domainresultget.com;
}}
```

Response header from this domain "www.domainresultget.com" looks like that,

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
CF-RAY: 11d864fce3900a9c-PRG
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename_title_download.exe"
Content-Length: 351744
Content-Type: application/x-msdownload
Date: Sat, 19 Apr 2014 10:24:48 GMT
Server: nginx
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
```

I want to save filename title into variable for future use ? I mean this one "filename_title_download.exe" I want to save this in to variable. Can someone explain me how to do this ?

Comment: Whole header is in `$upstream_content_disposition` variable, but what do you want to do with it?

Comment: I want to get filename and in response as a result give user my file with is saved in my server.. so user will receive my file with title from this variable.

Comment: So you don't want to change header, you want to completely replace response

Comment: yes, exactly...Can you help me with this ? thank you so much..